# Detaching an Object

Tags: animation, bones, mixamo

I have a defined character animation cycle with Mixamo. Several objects are attached to specific bones of the skeleton using the *Ctrl+P* -> *Bone Relative* function. Objects obediently follow the character. At some point, I need the objects to start their independent movement. Is it possible to automatically detach these objects from the character at a particular animation frame? Blender version 3.5.

Comment: In that case deparent the objects and instead use the Dynamic Parent adfon which will use the Child Of constraint

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to use the '**Dynamic Parent**' addon.